How to fix non-responsive Ubuntu
I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my VM machine on Windows 11.
When I do some actions like Ctrl+V, keyboard input, mouse button clicks, the whole system freezes intermittently.
It does not respond to any input including Ctrl+Alt+F1, only moves the mouse.
For example, when I copy a URL and paste it into Chrome browser, the system becomes unresponsive and the URL keeps being entered like vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv...
How can I fix this?
